# Android: AlarmManager - Repeating Date set to past - Will future alarms trigger?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

If I set the "triggerAtMillis" of the method
`setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)`
to a past date, will the future alarms trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the type you specify

Here is the list of types:

> ELAPSED_REALTIME — Fires the pending intent based on the amount of time 
>     since the device was booted, but doesn't wake up the device. 
>     The elapsed time includes any time during which the device was asleep.
>
> ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP — Wakes up the device and fires the pending 
>    intent after the specified length of time has elapsed since device boot.
>
> RTC — Fires the pending intent at the specified time but does not wake up 
>    the device.
>
> RTC_WAKEUP — Wakes up the device to fire the pending intent at the 
>       specified time.

So the answer would be yes it'll take that much time interval and according the the type repeat itself in the future.

Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for more